# What is $H^{-1}(\Omega,\mu)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

The space $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is identify as the dual space of $H^{1}(\Omega)$. In particular given $v\in H^{-1}(\Omega)$ we can find $w$ such that $\int_{\Omega} wu dx^{n}=v(u)$.

Now one can define $H^{1}(\Sigma,\mu)$ where $\Sigma$ is a compact manifold and $\mu$ a volume form for a Riemannian metric. Is it still true that given $v\in H^{-1}(\Sigma,\mu)$ we can find $w$ such that $\int_{\Sigma} wu \mu=v(u)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\Sigma$ being a manifold. If you really mean a manifold I'm confused by the meaning of $\int wud\mu$ since integration on manifolds should involve forms.

Comment: I have modified the question to make it clearer what i mean.